# How would I implement IDisposable for my classes so that it can be used in a 'using' block?

Tags: c#, class, idisposable

I'm coding in C# and I created a class that I would like to use in a 'using' block.

Is this possible and if so, how should I proceed and what to I need to add to my class?

Comment: `public class Email : IDisposable`, and then implement `Dispose`, and inside dispose clean up your resources.

Comment: While @DaveZych is correct in the implementation, the first question you should ask is: Why do I want to do this? Unless you have an actual need to clean up resources that may become orphaned or locked, then this is an unnecessary cosmetic application. It's a bad idea to go mucking with IDisposable unless you have a genuine need to manage resources.

Comment: You can use the `using` keyword with any class that implements `IDisposable`, which means only implementing `Dispose()` method. Doing that properly is **[rather tricky](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P)** and is only a benefit with large and/or unmanaged resources held by your class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `using` keyword can be used on any object that implements `IDisposable`. To implement `IDisposable`, include a `Dispose` method in your class.

It's usually important to also include the `Dispose` functionality in your class's finalizer in case users of your library don't (or forget to) call `Dispose`.

For example:

```
class Email : IDisposable {

    // The only method defined for the 'IDisposable' contract is 'Dispose'.
    public void Dispose() {
        // The 'Dispose' method should clean up any unmanaged resources
        // that your class uses.
    }

    ~Email() {
        // You should also clean up unmanaged resources here, in the finalizer,
        // in case users of your library don't call 'Dispose'.
    }
}

void Main() {

    // The 'using' block can be used with instances of any class that implements
    // 'IDisposable'.
    using (var email = new Email()) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Given the actual question (title), I'd say OP already has this information.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

That's all there is to it! In calling code you'd be able to do the following:

```
using(var mc = new MyClass())
{
}
```